# Вывести последний элемент массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript, функции

> Реализуй функцию, которая называется getLastElement. 
> Функция будет принимать массив и возвращать последний элемент. 
> Если массив пуст, то возвращать null.

```js
function getLastElement() {
       if (console.log(getLastElement([ 1, 2, 3 ]))) {
       console.log(getLastElement.slice(-1))
        return
    }  if(console.log(getLastElement([ 'one', 'two']))) {
       console.log(getLastElement.slice(-1)) 
        return
    }  if(console.log(getLastElement([ true ]))) {
        console.log(true)
        return
    }
       if(console.log(getLastElement([]))) 
        console.log(null)
        return
    }
console.log(getLastElement([ 1, 2, 3 ]))
```

В результате должно быть так:

```
console.log(getLastElement([ 1, 2, 3 ])); //  3
console.log(getLastElement([ 'one', 'two'])); //   'two'
console.log(getLastElement([ true ])); //   true
console.log(getLastElement([])); //  null
```

После вызова элемента, через console.log, должны получить результат. Последний элемент массива

Comment: А вы вообще понимаете что у вас в коде написано?

Comment: Ну вообще да, но это явно не правильно(

Comment: Т.е. вы написали `if (console.log(getLastElement([ 1, 2, 3 ]))) {` в здравом уме? Расскажите что по вашему делает эта строчка?

Comment: Я думал что при вызове console.log(...), в консоль должно прийти последний элемент массива. Я только учусь, прохожу курсы)))))). Спасибо вам)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getLastElement(arr) {
    if (arr.length)
        return arr[arr.length - 1];
    return null
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Если сработало, можете пометить ответ как решение